# Reading unicode string from file and displaying it on a GUI (QPlainTextEdit)

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding, pyqt

I have been facing a problem when reading from a .tex file that contain the character 'ç'. After reading a lot here on stack and the Python docs for Unicode, I've managed to read it but now I have problems when displaying it, instead of getting a 'ç' my gui is displaying a 'Ã§'.
My code does the following:

Read from a text file->convert .tex special characters->display it on gui

The function to read data:

```
def load_info(path, param):
    target = open(r'{}\{}.tex'.format(path, param), 'r')
    #read the line bellow on a stack topic and it seems to work
    value = target.read().decode('string-escape').decode("utf-8")
    print value, type(value) #here I get ç and unicode type
    target.close()
    return value
```

The function to process Latex special characters:

```
def LatexFormatting(self, text):
    print text, type(text) #Here I receive "ç, unicode"

    text = text.replace("$\\backslash$", "\\")
    text = text.replace("\\_", "_")
    text = text.replace("\\#", "#")
    text = text.replace("\\$", "$")
    text = text.replace("\\%", "%")
    text = text.replace("\\&", "&")
    text = text.replace("\\~", "~")
    text = text.replace("\\^", "^")
    text = text.replace("\\{", "{")
    text = text.replace("\\}", "}")
    text = text.replace("\n", "\\n")
    text = text.replace("\r", "\\r")
    return text
```

The function to display it on gui:

```
#I use exec here because there are several gui elements that I need to display texts onto
exec(u'self.ui.{}.setPlainText("{}")' .format(parameter_name, self.LatexFormatting(param_value)))
```

It seems to me that this is some kind of wrong encoding/decoding because it displays something but not the write thing.

PS: I'm using Python 2.7 and Pyqt4

Thanks for any incoming help

**-EDIT-**
As suggested in the comments bellow, I've changed the `exec` method to the `getattr`, which solved my problem.

Comment: Do not use `exec`, it is completely unnecessary. Use this, instead: `getattr(self.ui, parameter_name).setPlainText(self.LatexFormatting(param_value))`.

Comment: Actually just changing the `exec` for `getattr` solved my problem. I think the problem occurred for some reason because of the string structure of `exec`. Thank you

Comment: Yes, I think `setPlainText(u"{}")` would have fixed it. But even so, it is much better to use `getattr`.